# Why i am lose my Access Token in android?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-access-token

I am working on Facebook application in android.I am Running my application one r two times My access token works well after third time i loss my access token.Why,I am lose access token?What can I do for without lose of access token when run.

Any one Please help me....

Edit 1 :

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    mFacebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

login button click::::

mBtnFbLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("Image Button", "button Clicked");
            loginToFacebook();
        }
    });
```

login method ::::::

public void loginToFacebook() {

```
    mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    String access_token = mPrefs.getString("access_token", null);
    long expires = mPrefs.getLong("access_expires", 0);

    if (access_token != null) {
        mFacebook.setAccessToken(access_token);

        Log.d("FB Sessions", "" + mFacebook.isSessionValid());
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login SuccessFully",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



    }

    if (expires != 0) {
        mFacebook.setAccessExpires(expires);
    }

    if (!mFacebook.isSessionValid()) {
        mFacebook.authorize(this,
                new String[] { "email", "publish_stream" },
                new DialogListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                        // Function to handle cancel event
                        Log.d("FB Sessions",
                                "" + mFacebook.isSessionValid());
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Login Cancel", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                        // Function to handle complete event
                        // Edit Preferences and update facebook acess_token
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
                        editor.putString("access_token",
                                mFacebook.getAccessToken());
                        editor.putLong("access_expires",
                                mFacebook.getAccessExpires());
                        editor.commit();

                        Log.d("FB Sessions",
                                "" + mFacebook.isSessionValid());
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Login SuccessFully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();


                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(DialogError error) {
                        // Function to handle error

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError fberror) {
                        // Function to handle Facebook errors

                    }

                });
    }
}
```

Comment: Hard to tell without a crystal ball. Please include relevant code snippets where you're acquiring/storing/restoring the access token.

Comment: Ok, I edit my question an add my code.Please help me...

Answer (score 0):

Access token will expires for every hour may be you are running third time after that hour

Comment: Why it's expires every hour.What can i do for it's live.

Comment: Good question....for security purpose facebook has designed to expirews accesstoken for every hour....there is a very easy fuctinality to get accesstoken.....http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-facebook-connect-tutorial/    in this tutorial you will get clear explanation ...go through the tutorial...and have fun..

Comment: Thank you for reply.I am getting my access-key like this tutorial way.But still i am lose by access_key..After getting app_id any setting's to done in facebook developers blog??

Answer (score 0):

Superficially reading your login code looks ok, though using an old/deprecated way of using the Facebook Android SDK. (How recent is the example/tutorial you followed?) It is also missing access token extension code so it will stop working when the access token expires.

To continue working with this kind of Facebook API usage: Before attempting a Facebook operation, you should check `mFacebook.shouldExtendAccessToken()` and call `mFacebook.extendAccessToken()` if needed.

To change to the newer API usage style, use the `Session` class.

Comment: To expand on this, if you use the Session and Request classes in the 3.0 API, it will auto extend tokens for you when you make graph requests, so there's no need to manually check and extend anymore.